# How to limit PWA service worker fetch() to stay on "mydomain", NOT go to "mydomain.com"

Tags: javascript, caching, fetch, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I use a webserver on localhost for development.
The domain name on the local server is “mydomain” and the domain name on the public production server at the isp is “mydomain.**com**”.  This has worked fine in the past, but the service workers “fetch” seems to be going out to the public “.com” domain.  This got me very confused until I figured it out.  I would make changes to the local code files and sometimes the changes would show up but then revert back to stuff I had done yesterday (previously uploaded to the production webserver).  I finally figured it out and turned off the network access on my dev PC so fetches can happen only locally.  And then the weirdness went away.

How I can qualify the caching so that the cache/fetch/match does not go out to the production server when I'm running on the dev server?

My fetch is very simple.
It tries the network first and only if that fails tries for a match in cache.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(event.request)
            .catch(function(error) {
                return caches.match(event.request, { ignoreSearch: true });     // ignoreSearch=true allows us to add query vars to the url without invalidating the cache for that file
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: There's nothing in that service worker code that I see which would cause a change to the origin that's being requested. Are you sure that you're not misinterpreting something, nd your "production" traffic is coming from somewhere else? You can add a `console.log(event.request.url)` to your listener to confirm the URL that's being requested.

Comment: I did put in verbose logging and the url has no ".com", so only my local dev files should be fetched.  But I swear I was getting files from the prod (.com) server.  Perhaps there is some interaction with my local webserver (xampp) that I don't understand.  I changed the domain name on my local webserver to something completely different and the problems seem to have gone away.  So I'm rolling smoothly now.